# Is it possible to draw smaller rectangle in table cell in microsoft report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table with four columns. Column 3 is about mark grade (A,B,B+,...) and I want draw rectangle around it. When I drag rectangle into table cell, it auto resize to fit the whole cell but I cannot resize it smaller.

Is it possible way to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried to achieve it with placeholder and Interpret HTML tags? - also if possible share your expected output.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "resize it smaller" ? I'm afraid you are limited to the minimum size of the cell, which is defined by the parent row height and column width. Are you sure you want to use a rectangle though? When you say "I want draw rectangle around it" do you simply mean a border? Because you don't need to use a rectangle for that.

Comment: Ocean- I mean I want to resize the rectangle in table cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this can be done.  While you are currently inserting a rectangle to the cell, there is nothing stopping you adding *another* rectangle inside this first rectangle.

1. Add a rectangle to the cell in your table (yellow background in the screenshot below)
2. Add a rectangle inside this rectangle, and set it's `BorderStlye` to Solid and `BorderWidth` to 2pt (red background in the screenshot below)
3. Insert a textbox showing you expression to the inner rectangle (blue background in the image below.

This will give a layout as shown

[image]

That when run will appear as follows

[image]

You can resize this items to be the size you require for your report.

Hopefully this will solve you problem - let me know if you need further assistance or if I can help further